# How to get get the title attribute of a div element?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script. There is something like this in a webpage:

```
<div id="div1" class="..." title="
  asdsadsadasd&nbsp;&lte;...
">...</div>
```

I want to get its title using jQuery `attr` method. But it returns an empty value. My js code is like this:

```
$("#div1").attr("title");
```

I've tried alert in many different ways and I'm sure that the required element is selected properly and all other attributes are fine! Just this one returns empty string! ( '' ) Does it have something to do with being multiline?

**More details:**
I'm using latest jQuery (1.8.2) and my browser is Firefox 16.0.1.
I saw [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/FNJEu/) and it worked there! So maybe it's because something else. Actually I'm coding in a Greasemonkey script which is altering a webpage that is not mine to edit. So editing the HTML code is not possible.

Comment: code should work regardless of being able to modify html assuming that a title exists, and that you aren't calling code before elememnt exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `title` is blank because it (or most likely the `<div>`) is added via AJAX, after the Greasemonkey script fires.

Use [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891) to handle this kind of situation.

Here is a ***complete script*** that uses jQuery and `waitForKeyElements` to grab that title:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Grab element's title, when it is added by AJAX
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle   
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function grabDivTitle (jNode) {
    //***** YOUR CODE HERE *****
    var titleStr    = jNode.attr ("title");
    console.log ("Title is:", titleStr);
}

waitForKeyElements ("#div1", grabDivTitle);
```

Answer (score 9):

`title` isn't a valid attribute for div, but should still work. If you can change the html easily you could use:

```
<div id="div1" class="..." data-title="
  asdsadsadasd&nbsp;&lte;...
">...</div>
```

JS

```
alert( $("#div1").data("title"));
```

Also make sure you are wrapping code in `document.ready` so element exists when code fires. I suspect this may be your problem

```
$(function(){
/* your code*/

})
```

Comment: do you think you can get `data-title` invoking `alert( $("#div1").data("title");` - and there is a ')' missing BTW. You can add as many attributes you like to a tag. Even if they do not validate in some validators.

Comment: @Reflective  I realize can add attributes See: "it should work", regardless of validation. Have done it for years. I fixed the missing ")" previously. OP likely not using a ready handler

Comment: That's good, because it sounded like it is not a good practice :) Still think that you can not get the value of `data-title` invoking `$("#div1").data("title")` ...you should correct it

Comment: @Reflective  why do you think it won't work? I used html5 data attribute  `data-title` which is easily read by `data()` method

Comment: @Reflective   read the docs for data()  it works cross browser ... Lower part of page a whole section about html5 data attributes. The whole jQuery mobile framework uses it heavily

Comment: ok, didn't know it, didn't made complete testing actually. Thanks - it's good to know.

Comment: @Reflective can also place object ( or array) in as string and will read object

Comment: Yes I have experience with that :) Using attributes is very useful thing, because you store the data related to a DOM item into the item, which is the best place. Normally I serialize the data I need to store there. Usualy I use atributes to keep visual data - no problem to store HTML there - hover helps and many other helpful data.

Comment: @Reflective  I meant in the `data-` attribute in the markup. Object in markup string gets converted by `data()` mehtod automatically

Comment: Oh, that's really nice! Aucomatic conversion usually is safe and correct, avoiding possible errors. Really nice. Thanks @charlietfl!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the jQuery version.

It is running with JQuery 1.8.2 successfully.
I tried it with Chrome and IE9.

```
<div id="div1" class="..." title="      
asdsadsadasd&nbsp;&lte;...^+%:&/^+%6732045623459^+%?^+%)=1234114     asdfhj asklhdjflasdjfkasjdfasdk nf asdf as
 fsa
df sadf asd
f asdf 
sadf asdf sadf as
df 
sdfas 
f
asdf asdf        
">...</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LgkhW/2/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but it seems that the jquery ui tooltip functionality caused the problem. I ended up adding another attribute to the element that had nothing to do with jquery ui. I used the alt element, but if you're already using that you can use something like data-alt.

```
<a class="tooltip" 
    title="this will show up in the tooltip and may cause trouble using title later on" 
    data-alt="Grab this attribute instead of the title to bypass jqui showing the title attr as an empty string"
/>
<script>
    $(".tooltip").tooltip();
    a.click(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title'); // this showed up as an empty string
        title = $(this).attr('data-alt'); // this showed up as the text I was expecting
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fantastic solution. I found more on "data-" attributes here http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug:

```js
$("<div>").attr("tilte","dyanmic").addClass("test").appendTo("body");
alert($("#div1").attr("title"));
alert($(".test").attr("title"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="..." title="static">...</div>
```